# Convert a Tuple of Uniform Type to a List of that Type

Tags: c#, list, tuples

Let's say I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
(string, string, string) myTuple = ("Poop","Stack","Overflow");
```

Is there an elegant way to convert this to a list of strings that would look like this?

```
var myList = new List<string>() { myTuple.Item1, myTuple.Item2, myTuple.Item3 };
```

I can't `ForEach` over a tuple, or convert it into an enumerable it seems...

Thank you!

Comment: Your current solution is as elegant as it gets :) You *could* dynamically get all values from the tuple using reflection but why would you *want* to do this?

Comment: I think you can do it by index at least using an old `for(int index = 0; index < myTuple.Length; index++)` loop, see [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2.system-runtime-compilerservices-ituple-item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Tuple_2_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_ITuple_Item_System_Int32_)

Comment: That's... a really sub optimal dupe. Try [this](https://rextester.com/FWA42524)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to handle value tuples which have fields of the same type, for starters you can use simple reflection:

```
var myList = myTuple.GetType()
    .GetFields()
    .Select(fi => fi.GetValue(myTuple))
    .Cast<string>()
    .ToList();
```

Which will have some performance penalties.

If you have tuples of the same size you can just introduce the method:

```
public static List<T> GetFromTuple<T>(ValueTuple<T,T,T> tuple)
{
    return new List<T> {tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3}; 
}
```

Also using reflection you can write a small piece of code which will generate methods for all [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netcore-3.1)'s of different types (or create T4 template for it).